Server Sent Events without timed intervals
I'm struggling to confirm if the standard SSE approach only works with timed intervals, i.e. it's not event-driven, it's only polling itself on an interval before updating client.
Every example/post/video I can find shows setInterval/setTimeout in the handler for an SSE EventSource. However, my backend server knows when it's been updated and I just need to use that event to push the update to the front-end.
I know I must be missing something simple.

You can send to the clients at any time, for instance,
let clients = [];

// SSE endpoint to connect clients
app.get('/events', (req, res) => {
    // Set headers for SSE
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');

    // Add client to the list
    clients.push(res);

    // Clean up when the connection is closed
    req.on('close', () => {
        clients = clients.filter(client => client !== res);
        res.end();
    });
});

// Send an event to all clients
const sendToClients = (data) => {
    clients.forEach(client => {
        client.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);
    });
};

